# changing permission of table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I took postgresql dump and restore it in another db. I am trying to change the permission of the table in the secondary db. But I am not change the permission can't evn view individual table.

Whenever I list all the tables in a Scheme I can get the results but when i search for individual tables getting below error.

```
select \* from pg_tables where schemaname='testing';
schemaname |    tablename    | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity
\------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------
testing     | chatting        | postgres   |            | t          | f        | t           | f
testing     | report          | postgres   |            | t          | f        | f           | f
```

```
select chatting from pg_tables where schemaname='testing';
```

> ERROR:  column "chatting" does not exist
> LINE 1: select channel from pg_tables where schemaname='testing';

Can someone help me on this? I would like to change the owner of all the tables in this schema to a different user.

Note: I haven't create the tables, it is part of the pg_dump.

Comment: Well obviously the view `pg_tables` has no column `chatting`. If you want to select from that table, you need `select * from testing.chatting`

Comment: In addition in `postgresql.conf` for the new cluster where you restored the database change [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) to include the `testing` schema. This will eliminate the need to schema qualify the table names.

Answer (score 0):

The query that you should run is

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname='testing' and tablename = 'chatting';
```